# Can't rotate NSView

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, rotation, nsview

I've got a problem with rotating `NSView`

Let's say I have a `NSImageView` like this:

```
sampleImage = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,50,50)];
sampleImage.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];
[self.view addSubview:sampleImage];
```

That looks like this:

[image: photo 1]

Now I want to rotate this image by 60 degrees. I've tried several solutions to this problem, but none of them gave me satisfactory results.

I've tried with:

```
[sampleImage rotateByAngle:60];
```

results looks like this:

[image: photo 2]

```
[sampleImage setFrameCenterRotation:60];
```

results:

[image: photo 3]

Using AffineTransform and layers (I've set up `wantsLayer = YES`  for superviews as well) doesn't rotate image at all:

```
sampleImage.wantsLayer = YES;
sampleImage.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(60);
```

rotating with `CATransform3DMakeRotation` doesn't work as well:

```
sampleImage.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(GLKMathRadiansToDegrees((float) -marker.rotation), 0, 0, 1.0);
```

What is proper method to rotate images in OSX ? On IOS it's piece a cake: applying proper affineTransform work's like a charm - it looks like Cocoa on OSX isn't so willing to rotate views.